# Macbook Pro Late 2013 runs very slow after removed battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My Macbook Pro Late 2013's battery puffed up (getting bigger and bigger by day) and I asked the Apple authorized service store to remove it completely so that I can use the laptop as a PC (table computer). After the battery was removed, I noticed that it run very slow. I went to many suggestions on google and found this [Fix](http://www.rdoxenham.com/?p=259)
but I could not find the MacBookPro11_3.plist file (my model id MacBookPro11,3) to remove, other files could not be removed because of Operation not permitted. I also tried to run SMC and PRAM reset but they didn't help.

Can anyone help me? I really appreciate all your help!

Comment: IIRC, Apple's devices have massive problems like this. Specifically, when you remove the battery, the computer realizes that the battery isn't responding and massively throttles the computer's performance. If I were you, I'd get the battery replaced (or buy a battery and replace it myself).

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63613/how-can-i-disable-cpu-throttling-on-late-2006-macbook-with-no-battery - Good move taking it to a shop to safely remove / dispose of the battery.

Comment: @bmike I have the battery removed already by the Apple authorized store. Now it is very slow, I checked its CPU frequency at 800MHz [CPU frequency screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vems3cklsa828tj/Macbook_Pro_Late_2013_runs_very_slow_after_removed_battery.jpg?dl=0). It's like I'm using a 10-year-ancient computer.

Comment: Yes @leegor - the sensors throttle down the CPU to avoid pulling more current than the AC adapter can provide. The battery serves to provide extra current and stabilizes the voltage so the CPU can run at full power mode and full acceleration. This is how Apple designs it so you'll need a battery to get full performance out of that hardware.

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41045/how-can-i-disable-cpu-throttling-and-cpu-disabling