# How to keep 2017 Macbook Pro / Mojave from slowing down when not on A/C power?

Tags: macos, battery, performance

All of the guides that I have found are out of date.

My model identifier is "MacBookPro14,3".

One such example of "slowing down" is that when the MacBook Pro am plugged in, the application iTerm, is very fast. Whereas, when unplugged, there is a noticeable delay for every character typed. This is partially due to the use of oh-my-zsh and it's various plugins. But, the difference is night and day when plugged in or not.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify your question somewhat. *"...from slowing down when not on battery"* could be interpreted in many different ways, so you probably need to clarify what you mean by 'slowing down' as well as by 'not on battery'?

Comment: Agreed. Maybe some explanation what when not on battery means will help us find questions already asked or release the temporary hold on this. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63613/how-can-i-disable-cpu-throttling-on-late-2006-macbook-with-no-battery

Comment: Sorry, I misworded the question. editing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the specific issue that I was having in iTerm is solved by an option in the iTerm preferences to not use the GPU renderer when on battery. It can be manually turned off.